# static variable dynamically allocated

Tags: c++, dynamic, static

A static variable inside a function is only allocated once during the lifetime of the program.

So if I have a function like:

```
void f(int n) {

  static int *a = new int[n];

}
```

and I first call

```
f(1)
```

and then

```
f(3)
```

how big will the array a be after the second call?

Comment: Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @Liam I did, but I would like to know why it behaves like this. And if I already put the answer to it, I might get replies which don't fully explain the behavior.

Comment: How exactly did you try? How did you get the size of the allocated array?

Comment: The `static` keyword in function scope is just *full* of traps for the unwary.

Comment: @dmckee, can you tell why, or link to a reference?

Comment: @ViniyoShouta Two big problems (1) initializations in static context look like assignments, but only get evaluated once (the cause of all the confusion in this question) and (2) it makes the code non-reentrant (see the many complaints about `strtok`) which is a real problem in multitheading.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`static` local variables will be initialized when the control flow reaches the declaration for the first time. In this case, since the first time you used `1` as the `n` parameter, you'll be allocating size for one `int`.

Doing this kind of stuff is a bad idea. You should just use a local, non-static, `std::vector` or some other higher level container.

Comment: Actually, this is not correct. The control needs to pass through them, i.e., it isn't necessarily the first call. Consider `void f(bool flag) { if (flag) { static int* a = new int[3]; } }` and the calls `f(false); f(true);`: the first call will not initialize the array but the second one will.

Answer (score 8):

`static` variables local a function are initialized the first time control passes through them. The relevant section in the standard is 6.7 [stmt.dcl]. That is, the array will acquire size 1 and keep this size unless you change its size explicitly.

What's nice in C++ 2011 is that initializing the `static` variable is also thread-safe: if another thread reaches the instance while the variable is being initialize, the second thread is blocked until initialization is complete.

Answer (score 3):

Initialization of static variables within a function only occurs during the first evaluation of the static statement within function.   The first time when `f` is invoked with `f(1)`, the initialization for `a` will occur, and it will point to an array of a single int.  When `f(3)` is called, `a` has already been initialized, so the right hand side of:

```
static int *a = new int[n];
```

will not be evaluated again, and `a` will continue to point to the originally allocated array of size 1.

Answer (score 0):

The array will be size 1, since the initialization of the variable 'a' is only done once, the first time the function 'f' is called.